# How to change Card title style globally

Tags: antd

When Card title is too long, it's will became 'Lorem ipsum...'.

I would like to make the text to next line instead of '...'.

I manage to found this css can help, but where can I change it globally?

```
.ant-card-head-title {
    white-space: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost right...

```
.ant-card-head-title {
    text-overflow: unset;
    white-space: unset;
}
```

or `initial`if that is your preference. Put it in a `.css` file that you `import` into all javascript files where you add the `<Card>`

Comment: thanks for you reply.
Its possible to modify globally, make all card title to apply this style instead of manually import 1 by 1?

Comment: No the AntD theme has no support for this change. You can import the css in your App.js instead, then it will be global.